# Python: Mock a module without importing it or needing it to exist

Tags: python, module, import, mocking

I am starting to use a python [mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) for my testing. I want to mock a module that is imported within the namespace of the module under test without actually importing it or requiring that it exist first (i.e. throwing an ImportError).

Suppose the following code exists:

foo.py

```
 import helpers
 def foo_func():
    return helpers.helper_func()
```

The goal is to test foo_func() when 'helpers.py' does not exist anywhere, and if it does exist, act as if it doesn't.

First try, using the super cool @patch decorator:

```
from mock import patch, sentinel
import foo
@patch("foo.helpers")
def foo_test(mock):
    mock.helper_func.return_value = sentinel.foobar
    assert foo.foo_func() == sentinel.foobar
```

This works if the "helpers" module can be imported. If it doesn't exist, I get an ImportError.

Next attempt with patch, sans decorator:

```
from mock import patch, sentinel, Mock
import foo
helpers_mock = patch("foo.helpers")
helpers_mock.start()

def foo_test():
    helpers_mock.helper_func = Mock('helper_func')
    helpers_mock.helper_func.return_value = sentinel.foobar
    assert foo.foo_func() == sentinel.foobar
```

Again, this doesn't work if "helpers" is missing... and, if it exists, the assertion fails. Not really sure why that happens.

Third attempt, current solution:

```
import sys
helpers_mock = Mock(name="helpers_mock", spec=['helper_func'])
helpers_mock.__name__ = 'helpers'
sys.modules['helpers'] = helpers_mock
import foo
def foo_test():
    helpers_mock.helper_func.return_value = sentinel.foobar
    assert foo.foo_func() == sentinel.foobar
```

This test passes regardless of whether or not "helpers.py" exists.

Is this the best way to accomplish this goal? Does the mocking library I am using provide an alternative to this? What other ways can I do this?

Comment: While I'm all for unittesting I think that in this case you are testing a feature of the language and not a useful function of your code.  You might also fix your import in foo.py so that some of this monkey patching is unnecessary with an import guard (e.g.: try: import helpers except ImportError: helpers = None in foo.py instead of the bare import).  I mean right now foo.py isn't written in a to allow helpers to be missing and allowing that should greatly simplify your tests.

Comment: I really like the import guard idea, it solves a lot of issues. If I use the import guard as you suggest, I am able to use the first example I gave (@patch decorator). Thanks!

Comment: The import guards do not solve the problem: still get `ModuleNotFoundError` in the mocking code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're kind of missing the point of what a Mock is. You're supposed to build them when you want an object with a particular interface, regardless of how it's implemented.

What you're doing is trying to re-implement python's module system, plus it's a pretty horrible abuse of global variables to boot.

Instead of making foo a module, make a Foo class, and pass in the helpers in the constructor.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, helpers):
        self.helpers = helpers

# then, instead of import foo:
foo = Foo(mock_helpers)
```

Even if the real "helpers" is actually going to be a module, there is no reason you need to be messing with sys.modules and setting it up via `import` in your tests.

And if foo has to be a module, that's fine too, but you do it like this:

```
# foo.py
class Foo(object):
    pass # same code as before, plus foo_func

try:
   import whatever
   _singleton = Foo(whatever)
except ImportError:
   _singleton = Foo(something_else)

def foo_func():
   return _singleton.foo_func()
```

Large chunks of the standard library work this way. It's pretty much the standard for defining singleton-like modules.

Comment: This is really good info, unfortunately it would mean rewriting a lot of code, which isn't practical at the moment. But for new projects I will definitely try out this approach.

Comment: Maybe the "point" of the _existing_ mock structures is different but needing to mock a non-loadable / non existent library happens all the time e.g. trying to do local testing of a cloud-based platform.  So it is a serious shortcoming  that the requested capability does not appear to exist

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where the `helpers` library couldn't be loaded as it needed special hardware. 
Rather than make radical changes to the code that you want to test, an alternative is to insert a "fake" directory into `sys.path` as suggested by [how to add a package to sys path for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134718/how-to-add-a-package-to-sys-path-for-testing)

```
import os, sys
fake_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fake')
assert(os.path.exists(fake_dir))
sys.path.insert(0, fake_dir)
import foo
from unittest.mock import sentinel
def foo_test():
    foo.helpers.helper_func.return_value = sentinel.foobar
    assert foo.foo_func() == sentinel.foobar
```

where `fake` is structured as:

```
.
├── fake/
│   └── helpers/
│       └── __init__.py
├── foo.py
└── helpers/
```

and `__init__.py` has

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
helper_func = Mock()
```

Comment: It's a but ugly to hack the include path but this is the only way I have found to mock a module that isn't available or can't be loaded in the unit test environment.

Comment: Wow this is awful.   I seem to be in the same boat however.