# how to add a package to sys path for testing

Tags: python

This question is occasioned by instructions in the [python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) for adding a project to sys path to use in tests, which do not seem to work unless I am misunderstanding the instructions

I have a directory structure for a python project like this

```
sample/a.py
sample/b.py
sample/c.py
sample/__init__.py
test/context.py
test/test_something.py
test/__init__.py
docs
```

According to [the python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/), I should create a test/context.py file and add this

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import sample
```

Then, in my `test/test_something.py` file, it says I can do this

```
from .context import sample
```

The guide says "This will always work as expected".

but, when I `cd` into test and run

```
python -m unittest test_something
```

I get an error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

and the error message specifically refers to this: `from .context import sample`

Question: How can I add my sample package to the sys path correctly?

When answering, can you also clarify if the solution will handle absolute imports within the sample package. For example, my sample.a imports sample.b etc. When I had my tests structured a different way, I did an absolute import of sample.a, but since it has a relative import of `from .b import Boo`, it produced a similar error

Update

```
`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162 in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in module main(module=None)
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__ self.parseArgs(argv)
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149 in parseArgs self.createTests()
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests self.module)
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name,module) for name in names]
File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName module = __import__('-'.join(parts_copy))
File "test_something.py", line 8, in module from .context import sample
```

Update

if I run the following command from root directory

```
   python -m unittest test
```

It says , "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

If, as was suggested in the comments by @cuongnv, I run this from root directory

```
python -m unittest test/test_something.py
```

or this (without the file extension)

```
python -m unittest test/test_something
```

It says "Import by filename is not supported"

Comment: What version of python are you using? Pretty sure relative imports got reworked with python 3

Comment: Ugh, OK; can you post the full traceback, then? And the contents of both `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I added the stack trace. thank you. Also, to answer @DarthVader 's question, I'm using python 2 but am also making the app to run on python 3 so I also use `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of each file in the sample folder

Comment: @Leahcim if you comment out the `__future__` import, does it work?

Comment: what if you execute `cd ..; python -m unittest test` (go back to upper dir, execute by calling `test` module, not `test_something` directly)

Comment: @cuongnv see OP for update (sorry for delay, I was offline)

Comment: can you post your `test_something.py`?

Comment: @cuongnv I had already posted the relevant line from test_something.py, namely `from .context import sample`, which is what the linked to python guide said to do and which is what triggered the error. Unfortunately, I deleted the rest of the file because I found a way to run the tests by using a run_tests.py file (name of file obviously doesn't matter)  outside the test dir. However, I left the question posted because the problem it showed hadn't been answered (and the guide said it should work). But I think the rest of the test_something.py file was just a basic test case

Comment: I don't think it's related to sys path, but the way you executed `unittest` in cli. The proper command is `python -m unittest test.test_something`. I'm using exact structure like you and working fine. The output "Ran 0 tests..." maybe caused by test discovery doesn't work. HTH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Question: How can I add my sample package to the sys path correctly?

You're doing it the right way, but you missed declaring your folder to be a package. Try solution of Christian, it should work.

Your path is stored in `sys.path`. By doing this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

You're telling your python to add upper folder (of current file) into your path. As `sys.path` is a list, you can using other methods of list like `insert`, `append`...

In your case, you're inserting your upper dir at top of the path list.

See:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/cuong/.ipython']

In [3]: sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/foo')

In [4]: sys.path
Out[4]: 
['/tmp/foo', **<-- on top**
 '',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/cuong/.ipython']
```

So, from here, when you have

```
import sample
```

your python will try to look in path to see if there is any `sample` package.

Unfortunately, it can't find `sample` as you didn't make it as a package because your forgot `__init__.py` in `sample` folder.

Hope my explanation would help you to understand and you can handle other situations different to this.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but I had an __init__.py file already in both the sample and test folder, I just forgot to mention that in the OP.  So what could the problem be then?

Comment: I think I figured it out, you're not calling your `test` as a package. Try to execute this command `cd ..; python -m unittest test.test_something`

Comment: This comment should be in the actual answer

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an empty `__init__.py` to `tests/`: `touch tests/__init__.py` should do it.

Comment: actually, I had an __init__.py in the `test` folder as well as in the `sample` folder and it didn't work. I had just forgot to add that to the OP. Updated now. Problem is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had a battle to get my testing directory structure to work outside of an
IDE. Please find my solution below. Tested on
Windows 7 using python 3.6 and Linux Mint using python 3.4, running the code
using the command line:

```
python -m pytest test_compress_files.py
```

The file I wrote to be tested is called compress_files.py in a directory named
\src. The file containing tests to be run using pytest is called
test_compress_files.py in a subdirectory \tests, so the full directory path is
\src\tests. I needed to add a file called context.py to the \src\tests
directory. This file is used in test_compress_files.py to enable access to compress_files.py in the directory above. The _*init*_.py files are empty.

Directory structure

```
\src
__init__.py
compress_files.py

\src\tests
__init__.py
context.py
test_compress_files.py
```

compress_files.py contains the script to be tested.

context.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import compress_files
```

The line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

comes from the suggestion at the hitch hikers guide to python at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/. This adds the path of the directory above the /src/tests directory to sys.path, which in this case is /src.

test_compress_files.py:

```
import os
import pytest
from context import compress_files
from compress_files import *

# tests start here
...
```

Comment: sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)
GJ!!!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet but i was trying out Oppy's answers in python 3.7 env and it fail as:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'compress_files' from '__main__' (test_compress_files.py)`

I resolved using a modified test_compress_files.py (notice the removed dot) :

```
import os
import pytest
from context import compress_files
from compress_files import *

# tests start here
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, and slightly tangential, but this question/answers helped me when trying to patch on `pandas`.

I had imported `pandas` the "standard" way as `pd`:

```
import pandas as pd
```

So when declaring the import path I had to do:

```
unittest.mock.patch("src.path.to.file.pd")
```

NOT

```
unittest.mock.patch("src.path.to.file.pandas")
```