# Python ImportError for systemd service

Tags: python, python-import, systemd

I am trying to start a python script on a raspby via a systemd service, but it cannot find any of the modules installed via pip3 and gives the error:

```
raspberrypi python3[1017]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'
```

Running the same script via SSH terminal works fine. From my research, it could relate to the PYTHONPATH, though I have been unable to find it in .bashrc

The modules that cannot be found are installed here:

```
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.5.0)
```

This is the service file in /etc/systemd/user/mytest.service which starts the script unsuccessfully:

```
[Unit]
Description=TestScript Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/MyProject/my_script.py > /home/pi/my_script.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

How can I let the service know, where the modules are located?

Kind regards

Comment: You could run the command which python3 to verify that the python path matches the one you are putting in your service file.

Comment: running "python3 /home/pi/MyProject/my_script.py" successfully executes the script. But when the script is started via a service, it fails.

Comment: Does it still fail if instead of writing "/usr/bin/python3" in the service you use "python3"?

Comment: Have you installed the modules with `pip3 install --user`? If yes, install with `sudo pip3 install`.

Comment: Try [how-to-add-a-package-to-sys-path-for-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134718)

Comment: @StephanGuingor it fails in both cases and sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt was used to install the library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a quick fix to the problem:

By specifying a User in the .service file under [Service], the python script will find all installed libraries.

```
[Service]
User=pi
```